# Checkbox showing on Bizfx but not in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore-commerce, templates, commerce-engine, commerce-catalog

I am able to see Checkbox on Bizfx but when I do the `Update Data Templates` in Sitecore then its showing Single-Line Text rather than a Checkbox

This is the code to add a property. I have declared it as a bool

[image: model]

[image: model2]

In the Bizfx when I open the field for the first time then it shows the field as the textbox

[image]

After entering true or false, then saving the field and opening it again shows the checkbox

[image]

But in Sitecore it always displays single-line text. I have run Delete Data Templates and Update Date Templates but it always shows the single-line text

[image]

Has anyone experienced the same thing and how to resolve this?

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ideal this should work but tried removing Nullable type in property.From "bool?" to "bool".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change property type from `bool?` to `bool`:

```
public bool PropertyDetailsInOffer { get; set; }
```

`bool` values will be rendered as checkboxes for supported UI Hints, otherwise rendering as a string value.